# Why can't I insert 6 million elements in STL set?

Tags: c++, stl, set, max-size

I am trying to insert a little over 6.5 million elements(ints) in an stl set. Here is the code:

```
set<int> s;
cout << s.max_size() << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < T.MULT * T.MAXP; i++) {
    s.insert(a[i]);
}
```

`T.MULT` is `10`; `T.MAXP` is `666013`.

`a` is an array - statically allocated - (`int a[T.MULT * T.MAXP];`) that contains distinct elements.

After about 4.6 million elements `s.insert()` throws a `bad_alloc` exception. The resource monitor available on Windows 7 says I have 3 GB free memory left.
What am I doing wrong? Why can't STL set allocate the memory?

Edit: Here is the full code: http://ideone.com/rdrEnt

Edit2: apparently the inserted elements might not be distinct after all, but that should not be a problem.

Edit3: Here is a simplified version of the code: http://ideone.com/dTp0fZ

Comment: What does the task manager report for the working set of your process? Is your code being compiled as 32 or 64 bit code?

Comment: Most likely, you're running out of process virtual memory. What platform is this?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: There's no need for a big chunk with a `std::set`, you only need enough size for the node.

Comment: This should work. Probably some other code is corrupting the heap.

Comment: I doubt `bad_alloc` is due to corrupted heap. Possibly other code is consuming lots of memory and this set is just the proverbial straw that broke the camel's back.

Comment: How much ram is your process using when the bad_alloc happens?

Comment: Please show [a short, self-contained, compilable example](http://sscce.org) and state exactly what tools you are using (compiler, version, target machine, operating system, et cetera). It may be that something else in your program is interfering with this code. I was able to compile and execute it without problem on OS X (after replacing `T.MULT` and `T.MAXP` with numerals and defining `a`).

Comment: I just tested this with 10,000,000 elements and this uses only about 470MB. So, there must be something else in your code causing this.

Comment: @Matteo Italia: The task manager reports 397208KB as working set for the process. The code is compiled as 32 bit.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I am using Windows 7 and Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Not an answer, but have you looked at [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/)? It's meant for handling large data sets that won't fit in memory

Comment: @EricPostpischil Here is a a short, self-contained, compilable example: http://ideone.com/dTp0fZ

Comment: @MciprianM: That code compiles and executes without error in about 17 seconds with clang 4.0 on a MacPro4,1 running OS X 10.8.3. The compiler displays a warning that it does not recognize the pragma. During execution, the program displays “4611686018427387903” when run in 64-bit mode and “1073741823” when run in 32-bit mode. I presume that pragma sets the stack size to about 1.7 GB. Perhaps that is your problem. E.g., if, on your platform only 2 GB of address space is usable, that pragma leaves only about .4 GB for everything other than the stack. I suggest you reduce or eliminate that pragma.

Comment: I just noticed the pragma comment myself. I set the stack to 512 MB instead of 1.7 GB and it worked. Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

The problem actually lies in the fact that you statically allocated the array A with more than 6.5 million elements, which corrupts your program stack space. If you allocate the array on the heap, it actually works. I did some code change based on your description, it worked fine.

```
int *A = new int[T.MULT * T.MAXP];
for (int i= 0; i <  T.MULT * T.MAXP; ++i)
{
    A[i] = i; //for simplicity purpose, your array may have different elem. values
}

set<int> s;
for (int i = 0; i <  T.MULT * T.MAXP; ++i )
{
    s.insert(A[i]);
}

cout << s.size();

set<int>::iterator iter;
int count = 0;
for (iter = s.begin(); iter != s.end(); ++ iter)
{
    cout << *iter << " ";
    count ++;
    if (count == 100)
    {
        cout <<endl;
        count = 0;
    }
}

delete [] A;

return 0;
```

It worked perfectly fine with both vector and set. It can print all those 6.6 million elements on the screen.

As other posts indicated, you may also want to try STXXL if you have interest.

Comment: Aren't global, statically declared arrays allocated on the heap?

Comment: You mean `a` is a global array? You can dynamically allocate the array then pass the array as a parameter whenever it is needed, which should be trivial. Meanwhile, it is not good practice to use global variables IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

While I can't answer your question directly, I think it is more efficient to store your data in a std::vector, sort it, and then use std::binary_search to test for the existence of the item.  Storage in a std::set is relatively expensive compared to that of std::vector.  That's because there is some overhead when storing each element.

As an example, here's how you could do it.  This sorts the static array.

```
std::sort(a,a+(T.MULT*T.MAXP));
bool existence=std::binary_search(a,a+(T.MULT*T.MAXP),3);
```

Fast and easy.

Comment: not forgetting he already stores it in an array anyway (and the stl algortithms can operate on that just as easily as in a vector).

Comment: true enough, i was assuming the static allocation's ordering needed to be preserved but that seems unlikely now that i think about it again.

Comment: the main problem is actually that a is statically allocated, which corrupts stack space, if a is dynamically allocated, it actually works fine with both set and vectors. BTW: what are the "some overhead" when set stores each element? because it maintains elements in sorted order?

Comment: It seems unlikely that it is causing stack corruption.  It's only 6.4m ints which is around 25 MB.  No?  And I wouldn't expect that to bump into the stack space.  As for set's per element cost, remember it is likely using a red/black tree type implementation.  Two pointers (left and right child) and a color flag would be an additional 17 bytes per element.  Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).